# How to update python ssl version?

Tags: python, ssl

I'm working with `python3.5`, the module `ssl`'s `OPENSSL_VERSION` is old

```py
python -c "import ssl; print(ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION)"
# OpenSSL 1.0.0-fips 29 Mar 201
```

How could I update `ssl`'s version to `1.0.2+` ?

Comment: You should get a newer version of Python